# Atalho command + / parou de funcionar no xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Boa tarde pessoal, o atalho command + / para comentar um trecho de código selecionado parou de funcionar no meu xcode, alguém sabe o que pode ser? Pesquisei e não achei nada a respeito.
Quando tento usar esse atalho ele faz o mesmo som de quando acionamos command + z para desfazer e não tem mais nada a ser desfeito.

Answer (score 0):

É possível que este atalho tenha sido substituído por outra coisa no Xcode. Para verificar, vá em Xcode -> Preferences -> Key Bindings e procure pelo command +/atalho. Se você o encontrar, poderá selecioná-lo e clicar no botão X à direita para excluí-lo. Em seguida, você pode reatribuir o command + / atalho ao comando Seleção de Comentário.

Caso não encontre o command +/atalho na lista, pode ser necessário criar um novo enlace. Para fazer isso, clique no botão + na parte inferior da janela Key Bindings. Em seguida, selecione Seleção de Comentário no menu Comando à esquerda e atribua o atalho desejado (command + /) a ele à direita. Clique em Adicionar e você deve estar pronto.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).